# large table starts on the second page

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking

Why this table starts on the second page leaving a blank page? If I reduce its length it fits on the first page, but the page has the same size. I am puzzled

```
% This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.6.1
% see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net for more info
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[style=vancouver,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, doi=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=Fabio Cesare Campanile, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Page layout (geometry)
\setlength\voffset{-1in}
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
\setlength\textheight{17.001cm}
\setlength\textwidth{25.201cm}
\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep{0cm}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
  \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
  \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
  \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
%% List styles
%\newcommand\liststyleWWNumiv{%
%\renewcommand\labelitemi{{}-}
%\renewcommand\labelitemii{o}
%\renewcommand\labelitemiii{[F0A7?]}
%\renewcommand\labelitemiv{[F0B7?]}
%}
%\newcommand\liststyleWWNumv{%
%\renewcommand\labelitemi{[F0B7?]}
%\renewcommand\labelitemii{◦}
%\renewcommand\labelitemiii{${\blacksquare}$}
%\renewcommand\labelitemiv{[F0B7?]}
%}
%\newcommand\liststyleWWNumvi{%
%\renewcommand\labelitemi{[F0B7?]}
%\renewcommand\labelitemii{◦}
%\renewcommand\labelitemiii{${\blacksquare}$}
%\renewcommand\labelitemiv{[F0B7?]}
%}
\title{}
\author{Fabio Cesare Campanile}
\date{2022-01-20}
\addbibresource{LGBiBiblio.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} \fullcite{azin2019a}
%   Azin A, Hirpara D, Jackson T, et al. Emergency laparoscopic and open repair of incarcerated ventral hernias: a multi-institutional comparative analysis with coarsened exact matching. Surgical endoscopy. 2019;33(9):2812-2820. doi:10.1007/s00464-018-6573-6
}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio}


\textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
\textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
\textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

Studio retrospettivo con coppie appaiate

~

~

\textbf{Livello di evidenza}

Basso &
\textbf{Paesi:} Canada / USA

\textbf{Centri:} \textit{\ NQSIP}

\textbf{Setting: }Non applicabile

\textbf{Finanziamento}: Nessuno

\textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile

\textbf{Limitazioni}: \textcolor[rgb]{0.13333334,0.13333334,0.13333334}{rischio di BIAS (follow up limitato a 30 giorni)}

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }New Castle

~
 &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti con ernia ventrale o laparocele incarcerato

~

\textbf{Periodo inclusione: }Gennaio 2012– Dicembre 2016

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Pazienti con ernia ventrale o laparocele incarcerato con occlusione intestinale o gangrena

~

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} {\textless} 18 anni, pazienti che avevano ulteriori procedure chirurgiche associate ad eccezione di un ulteriore ernioplastica, adesiolisi)} &
Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica Vs tecnica laparotomica

~

~
\\\hline
\textbf{Note}: &
\multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{~
}\\\hline
\textbf{Outcomes} &
%\liststyleWWNumiv
\begin{itemize}
\item Mortalità
\item Morbilità
\end{itemize}
 &
\multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }\textcolor{black}{8136 pazienti totali che vengono accoppiati in base alle caratteristiche cliniche e demografiche (età, sesso, BMI, ASA, spesi pre-operatoria, classificazione della ferita, comorbilità) in 1642 pazienti divisi in due gruppi: 821 laparoscopico e 821 laparotomico.}~


\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Nessuna differenza nella mortalità }(1.3 Vs. 1.1\%; p = 0.653)
\item \textbf{%L’analisi univariata mostra che la tecnica laparoscopica è associata a:
Analisi univariata:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Riduzione della morbilità a 30 giorni (9.1 vs.15.1\%, p {\textless} 0.001);
\item Riduzione delle complicazioni di ferita (superficial and deep SSI; wound disruption; 3.0 vs. 7.9\%, p {\textless} 0.001)
\item Nessuna differenza nella morbilità a 30 giorni non dipendente dalla ferita (7.1 vs. 9.3\%; p = 0.105).
\item Aumentato numero di enterotomie non identificate (0.7 vs. 0.0\%; p = 0,031)
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{%L’analisi multivariata mostra che la tecnica laparoscopica è indipendentemente associata a
    Analisi multivariata:}


\begin{itemize}
\item Riduzione delle complicazioni di ferita (OR 0.35, 95\% CI 0.22–0.57, p {\textless} 0.001)


\item Morbilità non di ferita (OR 0.73, 95\% CI 0.51–1.06, p = 0.094)
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}
~
}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}


\end{document}
```

Comment: why all the weird paragraphs of `~` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as usual, they are the output of the writer2latex extension of libreoffice. I cleaned them up and the first row shrinked enough to fit the first page. You are great as usual

Comment: I am still puzzled about why a table that fit on the second page does not fit on the first empty page, being both pages of the same size

Comment: blame hyperref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\begin{flushleft}` introduces vertical space before and after the environment. Vertical space is dropped *at a page break* but not actually at the start of the first page.

The simplest thing to do is use `\raggedright` rather than the environment form, just as there is a common advice to use `\centering` rather than `\begin{center}` in some contexts.